# Localhost redirecting to production

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, nopcommerce

I have a small issue that I can't understand and i`m hoping someone could help me out.

I have backed up the production DB and restored it on my local machine.
I have changed the settings to use that DB, but when i start the project (either debug or normal mode), the localhost automatically redirects to the production site.

Is there a config file within SQL Databases that store redirect links? I searched but i couldn't find anything relevant.

I`m using nopcomemrce 3.3/.net framework 4.5.1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Trace your requests with something like Fiddler or Wireshark. It may well be that there are URLs stored in the production DB that point to production locations. 
Often it is worthwhile having a post restore script that changes configured URLs, e-mail addresses etc in the PROD database to ensure that a restore doesn't accidently try and re-direct somewhere it shouldn't or e-mail your customers when you are testing in your local environment. 
Even better than that, maybe ensure where you restore has no access to your production environment so you can't accidentally corrupt something

Comment: I have found out that the redirect was because SSL was enabled for the site in the dbo.Store table from the database. Switching the SSLEnabled from True to False fixed my issue.
Thank you for your answer.